# How to access ref of an element within custom react component

Tags: reactjs, ref

I'm building a Modal component. This component takes modal content as children and the button to trigger the modal as a button prop.

This Modal component should render the button. When clicked it has to position a fixed element exactly on top of that button that then animates to a modal dialog. For this the Modal component needs a ref to the button DOM element to measure it's size and position with getBoundingClientRect.

I want the Modal component to be able to receive through button prop both
button DOM element or a custom React element that renders button.

The api of the component looks like this then

```
const ModalUser = () => (
  <div>
    <Modal button={<button>Button</button>}/>
    <Modal button={<CustomButton>Button</CustomButton>}/>
  </div>
)
```

The render method of Modal looks like this then

```
class Modal extends React.PureComponent {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {React.cloneElement(this.props.button, {
         ref: (el) => { this.button = el && el.button ? el.button : el },
         onClick: this.onClick,
        })}
        <span>top: {this.state.top}</span>
        <span>left: {this.state.left}</span>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And thus requires any CustomElement button to expose this.button as a ref to it's containing button.

```
class CustomButton extends React.PureComponent {
  render() {
    return (
      <button
        ref={(el) => { this.button = el }}
        onClick={this.props.onClick}
      >
        <span>Custom</span>
        <span>{this.props.children}</span>
      </button>
    )
  }
}
```

For me this feels not optimal, but it works. I feel like there should be a more elegant solution to this. Does anyone have a suggestion how to do this better.

Here is a working demo
[Codepen](https://codepen.io/arnarbirgisson/pen/KqBpzW)